# How to reference phantomjs in sbt for scala.js?

Tags: sbt, phantomjs, scala.js

In the tutorial for scala.js (http://www.scala-js.org/tutorial/basic/), it says I need to run my code in phantomjs instead of Node.js.

But the downloaded phantomjs is an executable. How can I reference it in my build.sbt?

Following is what I'm having now.

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phantomjs": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.

```
$ vi ~/bash_profile
```

Add the path-setting command:

```
PATH=$PATH:/you_can_just_drag_the_bin_directory_here
```

Close your terminal and reopen it. Done.